# Trigger Polymer function using form onsubmit?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm unable to get a form to trigger a Polymer function when it's being submitted:

```
<form onsubmit="return _submit()"> //_submit is not defined
<form onsubmit="return this._submit()"> //this._submit is not a function
<form onsubmit="_submit"> //_submit is not defined
<form onsubmit="{{_submit}}"> //no output
<form on-submit="{{_submit}}"> //no output
<form on-submit="_submit">  //no output
```

How do I bind to Polymer function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `iron-form`:

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/form/handler">
  <paper-input name="name" label="name"></paper-input>
  <input name="address">
  ...
</form>
```

And then add a listener for `iron-form-submit` which is fired after the form is submitted:

```
Polymer({

  listeners: {
    'iron-form-submit': '_handleSubmit'
  },

  _handleSubmit: function(e) {
   // Do something
  }

})
```

See [iron-form docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form) for more info.